# Return values from lookup field in a SharePoint list using CAML

Tags: jquery, lookup, caml, sharepoint-list

I am trying to call in values from a SharePoint list using JQuery, which I have done many times before using similar code to below, but this time I am trying to call a lookup field and having little luck. Do I need to add anything to the CAML to make it work with the lookup field? I am quite the novice, hence I have hit a roadbloack at the first variation to the code I usually bastardise... :)

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var soapEnv = "<soapenv: Envelope xmlns: soapenv = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>\
    <soapenv:Body>\
    <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/' />\
    <listName>MyList</listName>\
                    <query>\
                        <Query>\
                            <OrderBy>\
                                <FieldRef Name='User' Ascending ='True' />\
                            </OrderBy>\
                        </Query>\
                    </query>\
                      <viewFields>\
                       <ViewFields>\
                       <FieldRef Name='User' />\
                       </ViewFields>\
                      </viewFields >\
     </GetListItems>\
     </soapenv: Body >\
     </soapenv:Envelope>";

        $.ajax({
            url: "LinkToWhereMyListIs",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: soapEnv,
            complete: Results,
            contentType: "text/xml;charset = \"utf-8\""
        });

    });

    function Results(xData, status) {

        var User = [];

        var i = 0;

        $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function () {

            User[i] = $(this).attr("ows_User");
            i = i + 1;

        });
        alert(User);
    }
```